# Text Classification with word2vec

Tags: python-3.x, word2vec, text-classification

I am doing text classification and plan to use word2vec word embeddings.
I have used gensim module for word2vec Training.

I have tried several Options. But I am getting error that word 'xyz' not in vocabulary. I am not able to find my mistake.

## Text processing

```
def clean_text(text):

text = text.translate(string.punctuation)

text = text.lower().split()

stops = set(stopwords.words("english"))
text = [w for w in text if not w in stops]

text = " ".join(text)
text = re.sub(r"[^\w\s]", " ",text)
text = re.sub(r"[^A-Za-z0-9^,!.\/'+-=]", " ",text)

text = text.split()
lemmatizer = WordNetLemmatizer()
lemmatized_words = [lemmatizer.lemmatize(w) for w in text]
text = " ".join(lemmatized_words)


return text

data['text'] = data['text'].map(lambda x: clean_text(x))
```

Please help me to solve my issue.

## Definig Corpus

```
def build_corpus(data):
"Creates a list of lists containing words from each sentence"
corpus = []
for col in ['text']:
    for sentence in data[col].iteritems():
        word_list = sentence[1].split(" ")
        corpus.append(word_list)
return corpus

corpus = build_corpus(data)
```

## Word2vec model

```
from gensim.models import word2vec
 model = word2vec.Word2Vec(corpus, size=100, window=20, min_count=20,    workers=12, sg=1)

words = list(model.wv.vocab)

tokenizer = Tokenizer()
X = data.text
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(X)
sequences = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(X)
X = pad_sequences(sequences, maxlen=10000)

embedding_vector_size=100

vocab_size = len(words)
embedding_matrix = np.zeros((vocab_size, embedding_vector_size))
for index, word in enumerate(words):    
 embedding_vector = model.wv[word]
 if embedding_vector is not None:
    embedding_matrix[index] = embedding_vector
```

Now I am using my created word embeddings on the downstream classification task.

## classification model

```
labels = data['Priority']
```

where I have two priorities. I want to classify it.

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X , labels, test_size=0.25, random_state=42)
```

I am using folllowing network for classification

```
model3 = Sequential()
model3.add(Embedding(input_dim = vocab_size, output_dim = embedding_vector_size, input_length = max_len, weights=[embedding_matrix]))
model3.add(SpatialDropout1D(0.7))
model3.add(LSTM(64, dropout=0.7, recurrent_dropout=0.7))
model3.add(Dense(2, activation='softmax'))
model3.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['acc'])
print(model3.summary())
```

I am getting error here:

```
'ValueError: "input_length" is 10000, but received input has shape (None, 3)'
```

Please help me to solve it out.Thank you.

Comment: What is `corpus`? More generally, if you get a "word not in vocabulary" error from `Word2Vec`, it's probably really missing – perhaps because it wasn't available as a word-token when the model was created. Notably, if the `Tokenizer` class is what's breaking strings-into-tokens, you're going to want to use the same tokenization before passing the corpus to `Word2Vec` – which needs lists-of-words, **not** plain strings, as each individual text.

Comment: Thank you @gojomo. 
I have updated my Code with corpus Information and text processing.
Can you please help me to solve it out.

Comment: It's hard to read your code here, as indentations don't seem quite right (especially in the `clean_text()` and `build_corpus()` functions. Can you make sure the indentations are correct here, and in your actual running code? Also, as mentioned before, it is strange/wrong to be using a different tokenization (splitting-strings-to-words) before and after. If you're going to use a class `Tokenizer`, it should be used **before** passing the lists-of-tokens to the model. (And, if after correcting this you're still having problems, you should be clear about where this `Tokenizer` class comes from.)

Comment: You can check if `'fin'` is even in your training corpus by running: `corpus_with_fun = [text in corpus if 'fin' in text]` then `print(corpus_with_fin)`. (It probably isn't, or at least isn't there 20 times to match the `min_count=20` requirement.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not all words from *corpus* will be kept in the word2vec model.

Replace:

```
vocab_size = len(tokenizer.word_index) + 1
```

With:

```
vocab_size = len(words)
```

And replace:

```
for word, i in tokenizer.word_index.items():
```

With:

```
for i, word in enumerate(words):
```

Thus ensuring your embedding matrix contains only words that are in the model.

Comment: thank you for the Inputs. Should I replce 'embedding_matrix[i] = embedding_vector' with 'embedding_matrix[index] = embedding_vector'? @Pascal

Comment: The suggested Code works perfectly for the embedding Matrix. I have edited the Code accordingly. I am facing the Problem in classification Task. Can you please help me to figure it out @Pascal.
It might be silly mistake. But I am new to all stuff.